# Are both nMOS and pMOS transistors necessary?

Tags: transistors

In theory, would it be possible to just replace instances of one with arrangements of the other?

Comment: Are you suggesting replacement of (say) the P part to form a new complimentary stage with 2 N parts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, we *could* go back to [NMOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NMOS_logic), but then everything would become as slow as it was back then. The speed afforded by CMOS more than makes up for its complexity.

Answer (score 1):

Yes You can replace but using nMOS or pMOS instead of CMOS will cost more power dissipation. But still if you are going for a little circuit you can design it using nMOS or pMOS.